# Cannot run node.js example. module.js:340 throw err cannot find module

Tags: node.js

When I type in node example.js to my command prompt it gives me an error message.

This is the code I'm using.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:1337/');
```

I got that directly from the node.js website and it worked last night. It won't work today. Some help would be appreciated please.

Comment: What is the exact command & output?

Comment: You're not running your _file_ correctly, chances are you mistyped your .js file name in `node yourfilename.js`

Comment: What platform? Win? OSX? Linux?

Comment: Rob the platform is Windows 7.
Command is node example.js. Output is module.js:340 throw err; Error cannot find module 'C:\Users\Daniel\example.js 
at Function.Module_resolveFilename <module.js:338:15
at Function.Module_load<module.js:280:25>
at Function.Module.runMain<module.js:497:10>
at startup node.js:119:16
at node.js:902:3

Benjamin. What do you mean?

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: @SLaks I believe so. I just created it in notepad and made sure to save it as example.js I don't see how it couldn't exist. Does it matter which directory I put it in? I normally save in documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js looks for the file you pass it in the current directory.
If the file only exists in a different directory, it will not be able to find it.

You need to either save the file to the correct directory, or use `cd` to switch to the directory containing the file.

Comment: That did it thanks! Saved it in my personal directory and it's running now!